# VLOOKUP not working with custom function when numeric

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have an item accounting page that looks for the value of column A, from sheet A, in column A of sheet Metadata. But! Column A (sheet A) sometimes has a prefix which is indicated by _D_ or a code separated from the rest of the ID by an underscore, like this: ddd_thevalue. In cases like that, we only want to look in sheet Metadata for thevalue, that is, ignore the prefixes.

I wrote a function that has been doing this for months and just today I broke it because some of the values in column A of sheet Metadata are numeric, when previously they had been a combination of letters and numbers. I could tell Excel was treating them as numbers because in the raw data (column A of Metadata) everything text was left-aligned and there were about 12 that were right-aligned.

This is the function:

```
Public Function CompareExternalID(External_ID As String) As String
    Dim outputReference As String
    
If InStr(External_ID, "_D_") = 0 Then
    If InStr(External_ID, "_") = 0 Then
        outputReference = External_ID
    Else
        outputReference = Right(External_ID, Len(External_ID) - InStr(External_ID, "_"))
    End If
    CompareExternalID = outputReference
Else
    outputReference = Right(External_ID, Len(External_ID) - InStr(External_ID, "_D_") - 2)
    CompareExternalID = outputReference
End If
 
End Function
```

I'm using this function on the sheet like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(@CompareExternalID(F235),Metadata!$A$1:$A$2000,1,FALSE)
```

If the value in cell F235 is ddd_thevalue (alphanumeric), it finds thevalue in column A of table Metadata. If instead it is ddd_485996, it won't find 485996 in column A of table Metadata.

At first I thought the solution was to make sure Excel saw all the values in Column A of Metadata as alphanumeric, so I ran this:

```
Sheets("Metadata").Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "@"
```

This made all the numeric entries left-aligned like the other entries, so I assume that now Excel is viewing them as text. But it's still not finding the numeric values in column A of Metadata.

What is going on here?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number formatting is a mask, it does not change the data itself, so the column is still a number. It would be better to change the output of the UDF to a variant and then test if the `outputReference` is numeric and if so, convert it to a number or leave as a string before returning to the formula, so it returns it in the correct type.

```
Public Function CompareExternalID(External_ID As String) As Variant
    Dim outputReference As String
    
    If InStr(External_ID, "_D_") = 0 Then
        If InStr(External_ID, "_") = 0 Then
            outputReference = External_ID
        Else
            outputReference = Right(External_ID, Len(External_ID) - InStr(External_ID, "_"))
        End If
    Else
        outputReference = Right(External_ID, Len(External_ID) - InStr(External_ID, "_D_") - 2)
    End If
    
    If IsNumeric(outputReference) Then
        CompareExternalID = CDbl(outputReference)
    Else
        CompareExternalID = outputReference
    End If
 
End Function
```

Comment: Blimey! That was so fast and did the trick. I am so grateful for everyone here. Thank you